# symbian C++ constructor

Tags: c++, symbian

how the private constructor works in Symbian C++??

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, Symbian C++ did not have support for correct exception handling, and based object creation on a two step initialization process --the constructor cannot throw, so there is a simple no throw constructor and then an initialization step. One of the problems with two phase initialization is that it places the burden of performing the construction and initialization (two separate steps) in user code, and that is error prone as you have to remember in each object creation.

To ease that burden, the design depended on static functions like `NewL`, `NewLC` (I don't remember if there were more of these). In that environment, having the constructor private inhibits user code from creating objects of the type without following the two-phase initialization, and forces them to use the provided `NewXXX` mechanism. These functions, being part of the class have access to the private constructor, and instantiate the object and then perform any initialization.

Comment: `NewL` and `NewLC` pretty much covers it, although of course particular classes can define whatever factories they want. `NewL` allocates and constructs an object (and might leave, hence the L). `NewLC` allocates and constructs an object, and ensures that it is on the cleanup stack (hence the C). Since generally the second-phase construction can leave, `NewL` probably has to put the object on the cleanup stack for that, and then remove it before return, so although `NewLC` appears to do more (and is more likely what you want), it does less than `NewL` for classes with non-trivial construction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any reasons for private constructors that are specific to Symbian C++, but there are uses in any C++ code, depending on functionality being presented and the controls against accidental misuse.  You may be interested in the discussion at http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?215249-Constructor-in-symbian-c